# Angular ng-repeat to PDF or printer CSS presumed alignment issue

Tags: html, css, angularjs, printing

I am creating some tickets to be printed out using AngularJS. I have try to produce a 1000 tickets and there is an offset of about 5 pixels from first to last ticket. Now as I was fiddeling my code I noticed the output is not the same. I believe it might be how the borders are treated but I'm not sure.

When ng-repeat start the class ticketNo and ticketNoR both are exceeding the bottom border of there relative parent(ng-repeated) by 2 pixels

When I reach 1000 tickets these 2 class are now 2 pixels above the bottom border of there parent element.

The result vary with Chromium and Firefox but there is always an offset. And I can't find where it's from.

This is my code and I realized that the fiddle dont reproduce the issue. I need to get rid of this offset for printing and auto-cutting.

Any idea where it is from?

```js
var ticket = angular.module('ticket', []);

ticket.controller('ticketCtrl', function($scope, $http){
$scope.ticketQty = 1000;
$scope.tickets = [];
$scope.pad = "000000";
$scope.ticketNo = 3000;

for (var i=0; i< $scope.ticketQty; i++){
    var str = "" + $scope.ticketNo;
 var ticketNum = $scope.pad.substring(0, $scope.pad.length -  str.length) + (i+parseInt($scope.ticketNo));
 $scope.tickets[i] = ticketNum  ;

}
    });
```

```css
.ticket-border{
 position:relative;
 width:800px;
 height:200px;
 border-top:2px solid #4eb610;
    border-bottom:2px solid #4eb610;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    margin:10px;
}

.tikNo{

  transform-origin: left top 0;
  position:absolute;
  left:50px;
  height:50px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-family: monospace; 
    white-space: pre;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    background-color: #4eb610 !important;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 60px;
    color:#fff !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
    margin:0px;

    }

.tikNoR{
  transform-origin:right top 0;
  position:absolute;
  right:50px;
  height:50px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-family: monospace; 
    white-space: pre;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    background-color: #4eb610 !important;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 60px;
    color:#fff !important;
    -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
    }

.tikNoDot{
  position:absolute;
  top:85px;
  left:35px;
  border-radius:15px;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  background-color:#fff !important;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
  z-index: 1;
}
.tikNoDotR{
  position:absolute;
  top:85px;
  right:35px;
  border-radius:15px;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  background-color:#fff !important;
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ticketLeftSide{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:55px;
  width:540px;
  height:198px;
  border-right:2px dashed #4eb610;
  z-index: 2;

}

.ticketRightSide{
  transform-origin: right top 0;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  right:0px;
  width:180px;
  height:160px;
  left:400px;
  z-index: 2;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-align:left;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size:10px;
  white-space: pre;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
     
}

body
{
  margin:0px;
}


.price{
 float:right;
  border :2px solid #4eb610;
  border-radius:15px;
  height:75px;
  width:75px;
  margin:10px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height: 75px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 35px;
   font-family: monospace;
   clear:both;

}



.headline{
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  left:5px;
  width:445px;
  height:150px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight:900;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.datetirage{
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  width:445px;
  text-align: center;
    border-top :2px solid #4eb610;
     border-bottom :2px solid #4eb610;
    font-weight:100;
font-size: 15px;
}

.disclaimer{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  height:50px;
  width:445px;
  text-align: center;
 
    font-weight:100;
font-size: 13px;
}
.logoImg{
  height: 60px; 
}


.webprint{

  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ticket" ng-controller="ticketCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="ticket in tickets" class="ticket-border">
<div class="tikNo">{{ticket}}</div>
<div class="tikNoDot"></div>
<div class="ticketLeftSide">
 <div class="price">1$</div>
 <div class="headline">Headline<br></div>
 <div class="datetirage">Date Time</div>
 <div class="disclaimer">Disclaimer</div>
</div>
<div class="ticketRightSide"> 
nom:___________________________
prénom:________________________
Tel:___________________________
Courriel:_____________________@
_______________________________
</div>
<div class="tikNoR">{{ticket}}</div>
<div class="tikNoDotR"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by css-border. You can use @media print and play around with the border thickness.

I had similar problem when generating a bar code. The bottom border always overlapped on bar code itself when printing from chrome or Firefox but it always worked in IE, not sure why it just worked in IE. You can also try IE and see if that works for you.

Comment: Wow cant believe that after all these years they are still treating borders differently. I just removed the borders. And where is the slight difference from? I mean after a 1000 divs with an offset of 2 px(border size) I end up 4px further. So every time the divs reapeat there is .0004 px difference?